# Dissolve Lines in Python

Tags: python, gis, spatial, qgis, polyline

I have a shapefile with multiple lines. I am looking for a method to dissolve all the touching lines. This was possible in ArcMap but can't seem to do it either in Python nor QGIS:

Before:
[image]

Desired output:
[image]

This needs to be done on multiple lines, therefore doing it manually like in QGIS merge is not an option.

In ArcMap I used to Dissolve and multipart. Not needing to use any attributes.

Comment: While the question is fine here, because you'll need specific geospatial packages, you're more likely to get better help at [GIS Stack Exchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com). Maybe [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/247067/ogr-and-shapely-to-query-dissolve-export-polylines) could be useful. Otherwise, add more relevant tags to the question here to attract more experts. But avoid cross posting.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I added additional tags.

Answer (score 1):

First you must dissolve all the lines, you can use this tool: [24.1.16.22. Dissolve](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#dissolve), then you convert to single part with the [24.1.16.46. Multipart to singleparts](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#multipart-to-singleparts) tool.